# Generate Sequence with given variance and mean

Tags: statistics

Is there a simple way to do this by hand?

I mostly want to do this for quick "straight face" testing to see if something works, so ideally I want (for example) a sequence with mean 1 and variance 2 with as many 0's as possible (for ease of calculation).

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: Is the given mean and variance the mean and variance of the distribution from which the values are drawn or simply the sample values?

Comment: Note that "as many 0's as possible" may not actually maximize ease of calculation (assuming you mean 'by hand', at least). If making the most 0's possible involves having a few really weird values, it might be better to have slightly fewer values but rounder numbers. What sample size were you looking for - is this prespecified or do you want to be able to take more values as you need them? "A sequence" might be any length - can I just give you three values and say "that's a sequence of values"?

Comment: @Glen_b the generated sequence can be any distribution. I hear your point about the 0's, but I'm sure what else to look for. The mean and variance are for the sequence

Comment: soandos - please note that there was a typographical error in the example (now corrected) where I typed a=1 (it's meant to be 3). All later values were based on the correct values of a=3.

Comment: @Glen_b, I figured it out, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "as many 0's as possible" isn't an absolute requirement but more something to aim toward, consider a very simple sequence of $0$'s and $a$'s.

If you had an infinite random sequence of 0's and 1's and the proportion of 1's was $p$, then the mean would be $p$ and the variance would be $p(1-p)$.

If the sequence was multiplied by $a$ (i.e. consisted of $0$'s and $a$'s), then the mean would be $ap$ and the variance $a^2p(1-p)$.

Consequently to achieve mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, note that the square of the coefficient of variation, $\sigma^2/\mu^2 = \frac{a^2p(1-p)}{a^2p^2}=(1-p)/p$.

Consequently $p = 1/(1+\sigma^2/\mu^2)$.

Once $p$ is known, you have $a=\mu/p$.

So in your example, $\sigma^2 = 2$ and $\mu=1$, whence $p = 1/3$ and $a=3$.

That is an infinite sequence of 0's and 3's where 2/3 of the values are 0 and 1/3 of the values are 3 has mean 1 and variance $9\cdot \frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3} = 2$.

(If you have a finite sequence, note the distinction between the sample variance with Bessel's correction and the population variance. That aside, the basic principle is the same.)

This may not be the *highest possible* proportion of 0's, but it's pretty high, and is relatively easy to solve for.